# Using C to program microcontroller Atmega2560

Tags: c, microcontroller

this a program that reads the pins 2 to 5 of port A and copies the state of these pins to the output pins 3 to 6 of port B without using AVR library. The program works, but i need some help understanding how it really works. I commented it the way i understood it. Thank you in advance!

PS: Useful information:
`0x21` - Port A Data Direction Register
`0x24` - Port B Data Direction Register
`0x20` - Port A Input Pins Address
`0x25` - Port B Data Register

`DDRx`, the data direction register which determines whether a pin of the port is configured for input or for output;

`PORTx` is the register for setting the value of output pins;

`PINx` is the register for reading the value of input pins.

```
int main (void){

unsigned char *ptr,data;

ptr =(unsigned char*)0x21;                    //Points ptr to 0x21, which is the DDRA
*ptr &=~((1<<2)|(1<<3)|(1<<4)|(1<<5));        //*1

ptr =(unsigned char*)0x24;                    //Points ptr to 0x24, which is the DDRB
*ptr |=(1<<3)|(1<<4)|(1<<5)|(1<<6);           //*2

for(;;){
    ptr=(unsigned char*)0x20;                 //Points ptr to 0x20, which is the PINA
    data=*ptr;                                //Saves the data from 0x20 to 'data'

    data &= ~((1<<0)|(1<<1)|(1<<6)|(1<<7));   //*3
    data <<=1;                                //*4

    ptr=(unsigned char*)0x25;                 //Points ptr to 0x25, which is the PORTB
    *ptr=(*ptr &~((1<<3)|(1<<4)|(1<<5)|(1<<6)))|data;    //*5
}
return(0);
}
```

*1: Is the program making a AND operation with the bits from `0x21` and the byte `00111100`? This way the answer would be something like `00????00`. I also dont understand the `'~'`.

*2: Is the program making a OR operation with the bits from 0x24 and the byte `01111000`? This way the answer would be something like `?1111???`. Why doesn't he use AND instead of OR?

*3: Is the program making a AND operation with the bits from 'data' and the byte `11000011`? This way the answer would be something like ??0000??. Whats the point in doing it?

*4: Why is he shifting `'data'` one time to the left? This way the answer would be something like ?0000??0.

*5: Is the program making a AND operation with the bits from `0x25` and the byte `01111000` (Result would be 0????000), and then a OR operation with its result and the bits from data? This way the answer would be something like `00000000`!?!?!?

Comment: Think in terms of setting and clearing bits, rather than AND and OR. OR is for setting bits, AND (with one's complement "~" of the bit pattern is for clearing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1:  The program is building the bit field 0b00111100, then NOTting it with the ~ operator to become 0b11000011, then ANDing that value with the contents of the address pointed to by ptr, then storing the result into the address pointed to by ptr.  It is clearing bits 2 through 5 of the data direction register while leaving the other bits unchanged.  Presumably, a bit value of 0 means the pin is an input.

2: The program is building the bit field 0b01111000, then ORing that value with the contents of the address pointed to by ptr, then storing the result into the address pointed to by ptr.  It is setting bits 3 through 6 of the data direction register while leaving the other bits unchanged.  Presumably, a bit value of 1 means the pin is an output.

3: The program is ANDing the value read from the data address with 0xb00111100 in order to clear bits 0, 1, 6 and 7.  The program is only concerned with bits 2 through 5 and ignores the other bits.

4: The program is shifting the value of bits 2 through 5 to the left one bit so that it is moved into bits 3 through 6.

5: The program is reading the contents of the data register, clearing bits 3 through 6 that were read from the data register, and then ORing in the new value of bits 3 through 6 before writing it back out to the data register.  In other words it is updating the value of bits 3 through 6 without changing the value of bits 0, 1, 2, and 7.

These operations are common:

`data &= ~(bitfield)` clears the bits specified by bitfield without changing the other bits.

`data |= bitfield` sets the bits specified by bitfield without changing the other bits.

Comment: Thank you kkrambo. This has helped me a lot. Everything is clear now ;)